# How to check for an indirect match while returning data from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to check for a variable within my array. It works if the number matches my value directly. How can I get it to match the previous value if it's below the match. From my code :

```
var assassin_bp = {
    fhr: { 7:8, 15:7, 27:6, 48:5, 86:4, 200:3 },
    fcr: { 8:15, 16:14, 27:13, 42:12, 65:11, 102:10, 174:9 }
}
var char_fhr = 48;
var fhr_frames = assassin_bp[ 'fhr' ][ [char_fhr] ]
```

with **char_fhr** worth **48**, **fhr_frames** returns **5**,
if **char_fhr** was worth **47** (or any number from 27 to 47), **fhr_frames** should return **6**,
if **char_fhr** was worth **49** (or any number from 48 to 85), **fhr_frames** should return **5**

I'm clueless on where to start. Can an object include a range? Should I have a function checking for it?

Comment: Is there any predictability to the ranges? Your current ranges seem random. Is that they way they actually are?

Comment: ...fyi, you have an extra set of `[]` around the `char_fhr` variable. Harmless in this exact situation, but should probably be removed.

Comment: Why can't you just use a for-loop to go through the array?

Comment: the ranges are defined by the previous (or current) data set. they will not change once set in the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the object properties and compare their names against your target value. See [`for...in` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [Working with Objects *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```
function valueForClosestKey(obj, target) {
    // get all keys smaller than or equal to `target`
    var keys = [];
    for(var k in obj) {
        if(k <= target) {
            keys.push(k);
        }
    }

    // order keys in ascending order
    keys.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }); 
    // e.g. `keys` is now [7, 15, 27, 48]      

    // get the "closest" key, which is the last one in the array
    if(keys.length > 0) {
        return obj[keys.pop()];
    }
    // if there are no keys smaller than `target` (i.e. `keys` is empty),
    // we just don't return anything (implicitly returns `undefined`)
}

var value = valueForClosestKey(assassin_bp[ 'fhr' ], char_fhr);
```

It is necessary to extract and sort the keys this way because the order in which an object is iterated is implementation dependent. I.e. it is not guaranteed that the properties are in the correct numerical order.

Comment: I don't think you need the Array conversion and the sort. The order is constrained by your ultimate `for` statement, which enforces the numeric sequence. Or am I missing something.

Comment: Changed my code to make it simpler, but in any case extracting the keys is required if I want to iterate over the keys in their natural order. The order of iterating over objects with `for...in` is not defined.

Comment: But there is no natural order for an object. The only order we can get is that which we enforce when enumerating. It happens that in the question, the keys appear in numeric order, but if they didn't, there would be no way to enforce it the original definition.

Comment: Right... I assume the keys are supposed to be in numeric order. That's why I extract them and sort them. Otherwise I could not be certain I get the keys in that order. If the OP wants the keys in the order they have been defined... well, that's not possible.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming we know where the floor is. If that can be known, we can just iterate the original object in reverse as though it was an Array. If we can't assume a given floor, then I could see that we would need to grab and sort the keys. ...Side note, you can just do `return obj[keys.pop()];`, since the default return value is `undefined`, but being explicit is good too.

Comment: ...I can also see that the `for-in` pushing to an Array followed by the `.sort()` may be more efficient if the numbers are widely spaced. +1

Comment: *"...may be more efficient if the numbers are widely spaced"*: Exactly that was my intent. Regarding `return keys.pop();`, I want to return the value, not the key. `return obj[keys.pop()];` would probably work in 99% of the cases, but it feels a bit wrong. *edit:* you were faster than me ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I updated my comment. And I agree, it's a little hackish to do. Explicit is better.

Comment: I think I even have a better idea... `if(keys.length > 0)` is probably easier to understand.

Comment: Is it me being stupid? `value` returns the lowest key value no matter what, in this case, 8.

Comment: @user173251, No, it's not you. I'm pretty sure this code doesn't work properly as is: http://jsfiddle.net/aquinas/t4WTe/

Comment: You need: keys.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); instead of keys.sort(). "Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted lexicographically (in dictionary order) according to the string conversion of each element." From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @aquinas: Ah right, forgot about this... that's really unintuitive.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! :D Quick question, as I'm trying to understand, pop() is used to push the array to get the previous key?

Comment: @user1732521: `.pop()` simply returns and removes the last element of the array. If you don't need the array anymore (like in this case), it's a quick way to access the last element in the array. You could also sort the array in reverse order and access the largest key with `keys[0]`... Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the tick next to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/aquinas/QP6aF/

How about:

```
var assassin_bp = {
    fhr: { 7:8, 15:7, 27:6, 48:5, 86:4, 200:3 },
    fcr: { 8:15, 16:14, 27:13, 42:12, 65:11, 102:10, 174:9 }
}

var arr = [];

for (var prop in assassin_bp.fhr){
    if (assassin_bp.fhr.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        arr.push(parseInt(prop));
    }
}

arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});

function calcScore(val){
    if (arr[0] > val){
        return assassin_bp.fhr[arr[0]];
    }

    for (var i=arr.length; i>=0; i--){
        if (val >= arr[i]){
            return assassin_bp.fhr[arr[i]];
        }
    }
}

//test to see if this works:
for (var i=0; i<300; i++){
    document.write(i + " - " + calcScore(i) + "<br/>");
}                    
        ​
```

Comment: Thanks! this works for me, however I'm trying to merge the function as seen http://jsfiddle.net/veksen/JtrLM I feel like I'm not too far :/